# Not able to save EMail and Image FB OAuth

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am using FB PHP SDK 4.2 to give users access via FB login. Everything just works perfectly fine except two issues:

1. M not getting any mail to save it DB.
2. M not getting any image of user.

Rest User Name and FB Social ID, i am able to save in DB.

Below is required code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(FB_REDIRECT_URI);

if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'facebook' ){
  $fb_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email'));
  header('Location: ' . $fb_url);
}

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
try{
    $session->validate(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);
}catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

$data = array();

if(isset($session)){
$_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

$data = $graph->asArray();
$id = $graph->getId();
$image = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/picture?width=100";
$data['image'] = $image;
if($user_obj->fb_login($data)){header('Location: ../');}
else{header('Location: ../');}
}
```

> **fb_login** function is used to save data in database

Comment: What API version is your app using? If it is 2.4, then you need to go read the changelog – it explains what has changed in regard to default fields that the different endpoints return. And what are you trying to do with the user’s profile picture here? Storing `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?width=100` into your database would make very little sense, since you can create that URL dynamically any time you need it, because you have the user id already.

Comment: picture i can ignore but i need email for sure... and reference for this code is from `http://www.smarttutorials.net/login-with-google-oauth-2-using-php-and-mysql/` .. m nt getting email at all

Comment: Don’t rely on outdated external tutorials, but consult the official FB documentation instead. Read what it says here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes under “Declarative Fields”.

Comment: @CBroe ... r u seeing any issues with the code above because m unable to debug thr exact problem

Comment: Have you still not read the changelog? I even pointed you very specifically to the part that is applicable here …

Comment: I read that already.. bur not sure where to chnage here in my code.. GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes .. i feel like here shall be change

Comment: That is an _example_, of course you have to modify it to the endpoint that you want to read data from … So what is the data you want? Profile data, endpoint for that is `/me`. And the field you want is what? `email`. And now the combination of both in the same form as in the example gives what …? (Be aware though that when using the `fields` parameter, you will have to ask for other additional fields as well. I would recommend that you test the request in Graph API Explorer first, and “configure” it there until it gives you all the fields you need.)

Comment: "In the past, responses from Graph API calls returned a set of default fields. In order to reduce payload size and improve latency on mobile networks we have reduced the number of default fields returned for most Graph API calls. In v2.4 you will need to declaratively list the response fields for your calls."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v23tov24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the email of the currently logged in user the user needs to have granted your app the `email` permission. Only then will you be able to retrieve it. You can read more about permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4).

Also in [v2.4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v23tov24) you will only get a minimal set of fields, for the `email` field you need to specify it explicitly in the API call.

> In the past, responses from Graph API calls returned a set of default
>   fields. In order to reduce payload size and improve latency on mobile
>   networks we have reduced the number of default fields returned for
>   most Graph API calls. In v2.4 you will need to declaratively list the
>   response fields for your calls.

So in v2.4 you'll need to specify the fields explicitly. e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email&access_token=<user-access-token>
```

Comment: Yup.. i did same just a moment ago.. anyways thanks for the reply.. here i accept ur ans

Comment: The user must have already granted the permissions in that case then. But you'll still need to specify the fields in v2.4. If you are testing with your own account then you can go to your app settings: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and remove the app from there. If you try to log in to your app then it'll ask for permissions again.

Comment: That i ll check but asking for access token is mandate or what?